# Four (4) Form On-Boarding Process

Tags: usability, user-expectation, mobile-application

My mobile application has an onboarding process comprised of 4 screens/forms.  The forms have 3, 4, 2, and 7 questions.  What is the industry standard user experience:  (1) saving data at each screen and allowing the user to complete the onboarding process where he/she left off at a later time or (2) having the user complete all the forms and if he/she does not complete the 4 forms, he/she begins at the beginning until he/she completes the forms.

Comment: Depends on your audience and the complexity of the questions.   As a user, can I easily complete the form quickly, despite having to answer 16 questions?   Also, is this for a captured audience (i.e. company employee who must register) or an optional (access to the site/application)?

Comment: The onboarding is for access to a mobile application for consumers.  A user can easily answer the questions.

Comment: Based on that, I definitely agree with choice 1, particularly when the last form has the most number of questions.   I might have no problem answering the first forms, but when the last one looks more complicated (7 questions when previous form had 2), I might step away for a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely 1). Save the data in between, and organize the questions in ways that help the user chunk out the process in a logical way without feeling overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data, allow the user to skip onboarding steps, track onboarding completeness status for users and send them a reminder: "Hey, pick up from where you left. You are almost ready to start using our app".

I was surprised by the number of people that got back on the onboarding step once they received emails that stimulated them to finish.